# Identify type structurally in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm reading the interview with Martin Odersky about Scala type system and the following has been said

> One of the aspects where Scala is more expressive than Java is that it lets you express these things. In Scala it is possible to have a type that says: anything with a close method that takes no parameter and returns Unit (which is similar to void in Java). You can also combine it with other constraints. You can say: anything inheriting from a particular class that in addition has these particular methods with these signatures. Or you can say: anything inheriting from this class that has an inner class of a particular type. Essentially, you can characterize types structurally by saying what needs to be in the types so that you can work with them.

Can someone write a snippet in Scala to show how can I characterize types structurally? After reading it I have a feeling that I should be able to do the following:

```
type CanClose { def close: Unit }
val closeableFile: CanClose = new File()
val closeableStream: CanClose = new Stream()
```

Comment: He is talking about structural types. Google for "Scala structural types" and you'll find more information.

Comment: About your example: it should be `type CanClose = { def close: Unit }` (note the `=`) and if with `File` you mean `java.io.File`, it doesn't have a `close` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala a type can be identified by its structure, enabling what it's often referred to as duck typing.

Here's an example

```
scala> def close(x: { def close: Unit }): Unit = x.close
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
close: (x: AnyRef{def close: Unit})Unit

scala> class CanBeClosed {
     |   def close: Unit = println("I'm closed now")
     | }
defined class CanBeClosed

scala> class CannotBeClosed {
     | }
defined class CannotBeClosed

scala> close(new CanBeClosed)
I'm closed now

scala> close(new CannotBeClosed)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : CannotBeClosed
 required: AnyRef{def close: Unit}
       close(new CannotBeClosed)
```

However, it's important to note that structural typing is implemented using runtime reflection, so it can have a performance impact.

That's why you get a warning on the first definition (you can silence the warning by importing `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls`)

Comment: I think 2.12 switches to `MethodHandles` and `invokedynamic`, so the performance penalty should be all but eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Martin is talking about [*Structural Types*](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#structural). It means you can can do:

```
scala> def anythingThatIsClosable(foo: { def close: Unit }): Unit = foo.close
anythingThatIsClosable: (foo: AnyRef{def close: Unit})Unit

scala> class ICanCloseResources {
     | def close = println("yay closed")
     | }
defined class ICanCloseResources

scala> anythingThatIsClosable(new ICanCloseResources())
yay closed
```

We only defined the *structure* of how we expect the type to behave, we didn't need to actually *inherit* any common interface, like Java requires.

In your example, `java.io.File` doesn't implement a `close()` method, so that won't work, but any other type adhering to that method signature will. One important thing to note is that under the hood, this requires Scala to defer to [*reflection*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), so that can be potentially costly.